# Which occurs first: nitration or oxidation of aniline by concentrated nitric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, oxidation-state, amines, nitro-compounds

[image: Two possibilities of products if oxidation occurs before nitration and vice-versa]

Which of the cases is possible or both or none?

Comment: Would definitely oxidise. Protect the amine but reacting with acyl chloride to make abide to make the aromatic ring less activated.

Comment: None, oxidative oligomerisation happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concentrated $\ce{HNO3}$ is ‘only’ around $70~\%$. To add a nitro functionality by electrophilic aromatic substitution, typically the $\ce{NO2+}$ cation is required which is formed only by strong dehydrating agents such as sulfuric acid:

$$\ce{O2N-OH <<=>[\ce{H2SO4}][-\ce{HSO4-}] O2N-OH2+ ->[][-\ce{H2O}] O=\overset{+}{N}=O}\tag{1}$$

Concentrated nitric acid is not strong enough to dehydrate iself. Thus, nitration will typically not be observed.

Comment: Not really, nitration doesn't even need any acid in some variants.

Comment: So oxidation would occur  first?  @Jan,Melanie Shebel